# DatePickerDialog cannot implement OnDateSetListener on MaterialLibrary

Tags: java, android, datepickerdialog

I am trying to use DatePickerDialog from [rey5137's material library](https://github.com/rey5137/material), but it cannot implement method OnDateSetListener. This is my code

```
dateFMCdialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                dateFMC.setText(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()));
            }
        },newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

This code give me error when I implement OnDateSetListener method. It looks like this dialog doesn't support OnDateSetListener. What should I do to get value from this dialog? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://github.com/rey5137/material/blob/master/lib/src/main/java/com/rey/material/widget/DatePicker.java#L430 it looks like the function is called `setOnDateChangedListener` and you need to implement `OnDateChangedListener`:

```
/**
 * Set the listener will be called when the selected date is changed.
 * @param listener The {@link DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener} will be called.
 */
public void setOnDateChangedListener(OnDateChangedListener listener){
    mOnDateChangedListener = listener;
}
```

and from https://github.com/rey5137/material/blob/master/lib/src/main/java/com/rey/material/widget/DatePicker.java#L72 is the interface to implement:

```
/**
 * Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when the selected date is changed.
 */
public interface OnDateChangedListener {

    /**
     * Called when the selected date is changed.
     * @param oldDay The day value of old date.
     * @param oldMonth The month value of old date.
     * @param oldYear The year value of old date.
     * @param newDay The day value of new date.
     * @param newMonth The month value of new date.
     * @param newYear The year value of new date.
     */
    public void onDateChanged(int oldDay, int oldMonth, int oldYear, int newDay, int newMonth, int newYear);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, chicks. But how I can get the old variable (oldDay, oldMonth, etc)?

Comment: It looks like those are passed into the callback function you implement.